# Javascript Callback Async Ajax YUI 3

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, callback

I'm trying to reduce code and simplify somethings by having a reusable method for making async ajax calls.  I'm actually switching to YUI 3 from jQuery and cleaning stuff up in the process.  This is probably super easy for you javascript guys to spot, but I've been trying to figure out how I can get my callback called without leaking memory. If I watch IE in Task Manager memory goes up very fast (the function is called every 1.5 seconds).

Basically, I have my normal web page that has the function I want called after the ajax completes.  I'm updating the UI from there and setting other variables that are only part of the page. I have a javascript file where I'm putting the method that actually makes the ajax call.  When I use the callback that I'm passing into that method it's leaking.

javascript file:

```
function doAjaxRequest(url, callback) {
    YUI().use('io',
        function (Y) {
            var cb =
            {
                timeout: 5000,
                on: {
                    success: function (x, o) {
                        callback(o.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (x, o) {
                        callback("");
                    }
                }
            }

            Y.io(url, cb);
        });
}
```

web page:

```
doAjaxRequest(myUrl, showContent); // Called every couple seconds

        function showContent(o) {
            document.getElementById('ajaxcontent').innerHTML = o;
            // Other Stuff Removed    
        }
```

If I comment out the callback line it doesn't leak.  I must have to make the callback another way, I just don't know what that is.

Comment: Which version of IE? Does it happen in Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera (read: real browsers) as well?

Comment: It's IE 8.  I hadn't tried another browser but just tested Chrome and it's having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating a new YUI instance with each call to `doAjaxRequest`.  Structure your code like this instead:

```
YUI().use('io', function (Y) {
function doAjaxRequest(url, callback) {
    // ...
}

window.doAjaxRequest = doAjaxRequest;
});
```

This will create only one YUI instance.

Comment: Still same problem.  Like I said though, it doesn't leak if I comment out callback(o.responseText);